# Mongo db convert NumberLong(Unix timestamp) to Date

Tags: mongodb

im new to mongodb im trying to convert unix timestamp example 1514428475 to readable date time.

i have tried using the mongodb shell but the result date is not correct it should be Dec 27 10:34am not Dec 28 12:51pm

> Date(NumberLong("1514428475"));
>   Thu Dec 28 2017 12:51:58 GMT+0800 (HKT)

Comment: Did you try- 
new Date(new Date(0).setUTCSeconds(1514428475))
in shell

Comment: > new Date(new Date(0).setUTCSeconds(1514428475))
ISODate("2017-12-28T02:34:35Z") i got this results doesnt seems to work either

Comment: I am confused the timestamp number you gave translates to the above date only. Try at -  https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php. Also monogdb stores the dates in UTC formats only.

Comment: ooh sorry i think because the results i was looking at was UTC+8. How do i add that?

Comment: _MongoDB stores times in UTC by default, and will convert any local time representations into this form. Applications that must operate or report on some unmodified local time value may store the time zone alongside the UTC timestamp, and compute the original local time in their application logic._ Check examples in [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/).